# Nastran RBE2 coordinate change

Tags: mechanical-engineering, modeling, simulation

I am looking for a method changing the coordinate system of RBE2 or RBE3 elements.

Below is the nastran description of RBE2 in Nastran user guide.

[image]

There is no field for coordinate configuration.

Now, I am wondering if coordinate change is possible or not.

Could anyone explain how to change coordinate of RBE2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RBE2 element uses the output coordinate systems that are defined for the grid points (field CD on the GRID card).

If you want to use two different coordinate systems at the same point in your model, you can define two grid points with different output coordinate systems, and join them with a zero-length RBE2 or RBAR element.

Note that if a grid point is used in more than one rigid element, it can only be a *dependent* grid point in *one* of those elements. But if the rigid element connects all 6 degrees of freedom at each grid, it makes no difference which grid you choose as the independent one, so this isn't a "real" restriction on what you can do - it's only a feature of the way NASTRAN works internally!

Comment: Thanks! I did it. My concern was 5DOF constraint, 1 translational DOF releasing in an arbitrary coordinate system.